# Trying to Post a JSON onto a URL

Tags: web-services

I'm on step 2 of an application process.  The first step was to use a GET method onto a URL and retrieve a name and email address.

Here is the URL:
https://mkpartners.secure.force.com/services/apexrest/careers?firstName=Homer&lastName=Simpson&email=HSimpson@Springfield

Now I'm being asked to POST a JSON Object.  Here is the problem:

```
Congratulations John Quach, you completed Step 1!

Step 2 is as follows:
Perform a POST to the URL you constructed in Step 1.
You will need to post an instance of the application object described below.
You will need to post the body in properly formatted JSON.
You will need to pass in all required headers.
Please set the isTest boolean to TRUE while testing, and FALSE when you are ready for your final submission.
application {
Boolean isTest (required)
String firstName (required)
String lastName (required)
String email (required)
String phone (required)
String zipcode (required)
String describeYourself (required)
ool[] objectLanguages (required)
education[] education (required)
experience[] experience (required)
certification[] certs
}

education {
String school (required)
Integer graduationYear (required)
String degree (required)
String major (required)
}

experience {
String company (required)
Date fromDate [yyyy-MM-dd] (required)
Date toDate [yyyy-MM-dd] (required)
String title (required)
String workDone (required)
}

certification {
String certification (required)
Date dateCertified [yyyy-MM-dd] (required)
}

ool {
String language (required) [must include at least 'javascript'; include any other OOP languages you know]
Integer proficiency (required) [scale of 0-10, 0 being none, 10 being proficient]
}

A successful post will result in a code 202 and you will receive an automated email confirmation. Good Luck!
```

I've tried many codes.  I've followed your suggestion and used this based on the code you've given.  I'm using javascript through an HTML page.

```
 <script> 
var webLink = "https://mkpartners.secure.force.com/services/apexrest/careers?firstName=John&lastName=Quach&email=johnq1216@gmail.com"; 


var apply = {
         isTest : false,
         firstName : "John",
         lastName : "Quach",
         email : "johnq1216@gmail.com",
         phone : 6269355016,
         zipcode : 91207,
         describeYourself : "Self Taught Programmer and Developer"
    }


function httpPost(theUrl) {
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();         
    xmlHttp.open( "POST", theUrl, false);    
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"); 
    xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(apply)); 
}  


httpPost(webLink); 
</script>
//This script will make a POST request. Read above comments.
```

Of course none of it works.  What am I doing wrong?  Do I need the complete JSON Object with the Language, Education, and Certification objects nested in?  The reason I left them out is because I want to get some response from the website and I wanted to keep the answer small.

Do I need more than just a notepad on my computer to get this JSON object to be posted to the URL?

Comment: 1. That's not JSON; 2. Why do you use "GET" if you need to "POST"?

Answer (score 1):

```
//You will still have to do the JSON encoding. Use the JSON encoder for this and then make the request. Pass the JSON object you get after processing into http post as a parameter.
<script> 
var webLink = "https://mkpartners.secure.force.com/services/apexrest/careers"; 
var moreSimplified = { firstName : "John", lastName : "Quach", email : "johnq1216@gmail.com" } 
function httpPost(theUrl) {
var xmlHttp = null;
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();         
xmlHttp.open( "POST", theUrl, false);    
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"); 
xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(moreSimplified)); 
}  
httpPost(webLink); 
</script>
//This script will make a POST request. Read above comments.
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not getting anything.  I've reedited my original post to reflect your changes with some minor tweaking of my own.  What do I need to do to get a specific response from that URL's link?  Do I need more than notepad on my windows computer?

Comment: Ok, I think I located the area where the problem was.  I've noticed that once Javascript fails to run a statement, it will ignore any statements after that.  I've removed the statement "setRequestHeader" and I've noticed text on my lower left corner of chrome that says its trying to establish a connection to the URL.

Comment: @user1623873 you were not getting anything because you are not supposed to if you don't encode your JSON. First encode your JSON and then post.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is invalid

```
var json =   {
    firstName : "John",
    lastName : "Quach",
    email : "johnq1216@gmail.com"
};
```

xmlhttp.send(string) work only with POST verb

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", ,"demo_post.asp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(json);
```

Comment: Can you check my answer? Its actually good. Just i haven't added code for JSON encoding.